# How to extract tables from this website with Python and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to extract the data from 1 table on this website but I am unable to find any of them.
I have already checked some answers to similar questions but none of them seem to work.

That is my code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
url = "https://www.home.saxo/en-gb/insights/tools/fx-options-risk-tool/tool-details" 

response = requests.get(url,headers=hdr)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

#find all tables

soup.find_all('tables')
```

I am particularly interested into one of them and below the code to extract its headings:

```
vol_table = soup.find("table", attrs={"class": "volTable"})
vol_table_data = vol_table.tbody.find_all("tr") 

# Get all the headings of Lists
headings = []
for td in vol_table_data[0].find_all("td"):
    # remove any newlines and extra spaces from left and right
    headings.append(td.b.text.replace('\n', ' ').strip())

print(headings)
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: are they generated on the fly by javascript based on an AJAX call. get the URL with `curl` or `wget` and inspect the HTML you get in return. then you need to perform the AJAX yourself an  analyze the XLM or JSON returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table is loaded from different URL. Use this example to load data from the first table:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://fxowebtools.saxobank.com/otc.html'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

for pair, spot in zip(soup.select('td.volPair'), soup.select('td.spot')):
    print(pair.text, spot.text)
```

Prints:

```
EURUSD 1.1836 (0.34%)
USDJPY 104.33 (-0.25%)
GBPUSD 1.2968 (0.74%)
AUDUSD 0.7285 (-0.22%)
USDCAD 1.3194 (-0.10%)
USDCHF 0.9104 (-0.02%)
EURJPY 123.49 (0.08%)
EURGBP 0.9128 (-0.41%)
EURCHF 1.0776 (0.32%)
XAUUSD 1948.13 (0.28%)
XAGUSD 26.9086 (0.24%)
EURUSD 1.1836 (0.34%)
USDJPY 104.33 (-0.25%)
GBPUSD 1.2968 (0.74%)
AUDUSD 0.7285 (-0.22%)
USDCAD 1.3194 (-0.10%)
USDCHF 0.9104 (-0.02%)
EURJPY 123.49 (0.08%)
EURGBP 0.9128 (-0.41%)
EURCHF 1.0776 (0.32%)
XAUUSD 1948.13 (0.28%)
XAGUSD 26.9086 (0.24%)
```